# Hashicorp Vault - 403 when making api call

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I've got a (possible) strange behavior when trying to get secrets from the vault.

Setup:

1. Vault 1.2.2
2. Very basic KV secret
3. Token with the associated policy associated that allows reading this secret.

I successfully can read that secret using vault agent:

```
root@us-border-proxy# env | grep VAULT

VAULT_TOKEN=BLABLA
VAULT_CACERT=./vault-ca.crt
VAULT_ADDR=https://1.1.1.1:8200

root@us-border-proxy# vault kv get secret/example
=== Data ===
Key    Value
---    -----
key    SECRETPASSWORD
```

But the problem starts when I trying to do the same using vault API - I just got 403:

```
root@us-border-proxy# curl -k -H "X-Vault-Token: BLABLA" -X GET https://1.1.1.1:8200/v1/secret/data/example

{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: "Token with associated policy associated that allows to read this secret." can you add the policy that you used to create the token?

Answer (score 0):

> Got your error

**When you are listing from CLI, the path you mentioned is `secret/example`**

```
root@us-border-proxy# vault kv get secret/example
=== Data ===
Key    Value
---    -----
key    SECRETPASSWORD
```

**But while the path in the `curl` command is `secret/data/example`**

```
curl -k -H "X-Vault-Token: BLABLA" -X GET https://1.1.1.1:8200/v1/secret/data/example
```

**So changing to `secret/example` should work.**